# Paypal Standard Payment Option not showing in admin

Tags: magento, paypal, magento2, admin, payment-gateway

I want to integrated the paypal standard  option to my store, but unfortunately it is not visible on the admin side, Only the Express Checkout is there,

Also checked in the Dropdown of other paypal payment methods but it is empty.

any Idea how to enable it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Happy to be of any help!

PayPal standard is deprecated a long time ago and it has been removed in all Magento 2.x versions. You can choose the PayPal express checkout option as it is pre-built and easy to configure.

Also, it has got a shortcut button [Cart & Product page] which customers prefer to use.

Thanks.

Comment: I mean the other payment methods are not visible at all. and i just explore if you change the Merchant Country other methods will be shown.

Comment: As mentioned above, the other standard modules have been removed.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to enable PayPal Standard by default on new sites, please add the following code snippet:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_should_load_paypal_standard', '__return_true' );
```

This is only working on woocommerce in wordpress because Only for new installs with WooCommerce 5.5 and above, PayPal Standard which is included in WooCommerce core will not be loaded by default. Use this in functions.php

For magento read the documentation in magento update by version. Actually for paypal security reasons these changes are applied most of the framworks